How to train a neural network to identify multiple features in one image, where the order of predicted features doesn't matter
I recently created a toy dataset for myself, which I call "multi-color MNIST", where multiple digits with different colors appear on a single RGB image. See the image I attached. I am using a conv->dense neural network built in PyTorch to look an image and provide as output the digits and their respective colors.
Each digit-color combination is represented by a one-hot vector with shape (10*num_colors). In the simple case of two digits per image and two colors (e.g. red, blue) I realized that the following could occur and the neural network would be punished even though it got the answer correct:
#         |       red        |      blue          | 
y_data = [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], # red 2
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] # blue 3

y_pred = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], # blue 3
          [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] # red 2

My question is: how do I create a loss function or modify the output layer of my neural network so that the order of the neural network's outputs doesn't matter and the above example would be a correct prediction; even though as they are now y_data isn't identical to y_pred.
I know that was a lot so thank you if you made it this far :)


a couple things that might be worth trying: 1) have the loss be the minimum of the loss of the network's outputs and the output transposed 2) have it be the sum of the two insetad 3) sum the one-hot representations and also the network outputs along axis 0 and use MSE loss
